# Problem with lightning:input type="radio" checked attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In this [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) markup, the initial checked state defined via the `checked` attribute is ignored leaving both radio buttons unchecked:

```
<div class="slds-form--stacked">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <lightning:input type="radio"
                         label="Default"
                         aura:id="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                         name="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                         value="DEFAULT"
                         checked="true"
                         />
        <lightning:input type="radio"
                         label="Estate Of"
                         aura:id="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                         name="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                         value="ESTATE_OF"
                         checked="false"
                         />
    </div>
</div>
```

Removing the `name="RELATED_OPTIONS"` (that ensures only one is checked) avoids the problem but then requires explicit code to uncheck the unselected option.

Is there a cleaner way to make this work?

**PS**

This is inside a couple of layers of `lightning:tabset`/`lightning:tab` that may be having some influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below and it worked for me. it set the first radio to checked correctly.Can you check your console to see if there is any markup error in console?

```
<lightning:input type="radio"
                     label="Default"
                     aura:id="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                     name="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                     checked="true"
                     />
    <lightning:input type="radio"
                     label="Estate Of"
                     aura:id="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                     name="RELATED_OPTIONS"
                     value="ESTATE_OF"
                   />
```

Comment: Thanks - just tried that and it didn't help. My problem may relate to other stuff in the component; I've added a PS about one of the bits of other stuff. Good to know the component does basically work.

Comment: I tried putting the code inside a lightning:tabset and it still works for me. Like you said it could be something else and maybe a CSS issue.